# Несколько условий в SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Мне нужно сделать запрос к БД, в котором необходимо выполнить выборку по условиям.
Причем условий 5, необходимо выполнение хотя бы 4х. Как можно это сделать не прибегая к сложнейшим вариантам с AND OR. Подскажите, как )

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с подзапросом и кейсами

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      t.*,
      CASE WHEN [условие1] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END op1,
      CASE WHEN [условие2] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END op2,
      CASE WHEN [условие3] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END op3,
      CASE WHEN [условие4] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END op4,
      CASE WHEN [условие5] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END op5
    FROM
      table t
  ) tmp
WHERE
  op1 + op2 + op3 + op4 + op5 >= 4
```

Comment: Кстати, в MySQL любое логическое условие дает 0 или 1. так что вполне можно сходу писать `(a=1)+(b=2)+...>=4`

Comment: Mike, спасибо, жаль раньше этого не знал.